# How can I typeset a brace on the right-hand side of two equations?

Tags: braces

How to obtein this on latex?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered the `rcases` environment of the `mathtools` package?

Comment: no how to considered it  ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: A good starting point is reading the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf) of the package usually.

Comment: I've posted an answer with two possible solutions, one using an `array` environment, the other an `rcases` environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two methods for creating the output you're interested in. One involves the use of an `array` environment, and the other that of an `rcases` environment. The latter method requires less typing; however, it does require you to load the `mathtools` package -- which you may be doing anyway. Aside: If you use `drcases` instead of `dcases`, you could omit the two `\displaystyle` directives, for further savings in terms of typing effort.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'rcases' environment
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
With \texttt{array} environment:

\[ 
\left.\begin{array}{ll}
  \displaystyle \int_\Omega f L(g)\,dx\\[2ex]
  \displaystyle \int_\Omega g L(f)\,dx
\end{array}\right\}
\]

\bigskip
With \texttt{rcases} environment:

\[
\begin{rcases}
  \displaystyle \int_\Omega f L(g)\,dx\\
  \displaystyle \int_\Omega g L(f)\,dx
\end{rcases}
\]
 \end{document}
```